# Asp.Net MVC application Property is always null after Application_Start() is called

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-asax

I have the following global.asax for my MVC application. Everytime a request starts, I add the `ApplicationContext`(which has some objects such as Tokenfactory to handle authentication etc) to each request in `Application_BeginRequest()`. Even though the `ApplicationContext` is instantiated correctly in `Application_Start()`, it is null every time `Application_BeginRequest()` is called.

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication {

    /// <summary>
    /// Application context which can be accessed server wide. It contains Tokenfactory etc.
    /// </summary>
    public ApplicationContext ApplicationContext { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Runs once when application starts.
    /// </summary>
    protected void Application_Start() {
        //STUFF...
        //........
        InitializeContext();
    }

    private void InitializeContext() {
        ApplicationContext = new ApplicationContext();
    }

    protected void Application_BeginRequest() {
        Context.Items.Add("TokenFactory", ApplicationContext.tokenFactory);
    }
}
```

Extra info:

If I change this line to

```
public ApplicationContext ApplicationContext { get; private set; }
```

this➡ (and of course remove `InitializeContext();` :P)

```
public ApplicationContext ApplicationContext { get; } = new ApplicationContext();
```

It works without problems! What is the reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Application_Start()` fires only once, where as `Application_BeginRequest()` fires with each request. In your case `ApplicationContext` is not `static`, and it is only getting initialized in `Application_Start()`. So it will only be available on the application start, for the remaining request it will not be available.

You can make it `static`, if it is not persisting any state, or initialize it again with every request you are receiving.

> `public ApplicationContext ApplicationContext { get; } = new
>   ApplicationContext();`
>
> It works without problems! What is the reason
>    for this behavior?

This will definitely work, as every time `MvcApplication` is instantiated, a new instance of `ApplicationContext` is being created.

Comment: I was under the impression that there exists only one application, it seems that IIS creates more than one instance of MvcApplication. `ApplicationContext` is initalized correctly for the first instance but other instances, it is `null`

Comment: Not getting your comment clearly, but if you want only once instate all the time, you can go for static.

Comment: I think you are supposed to fix the following➡"This will definitely work, as every time you are accessing the property a new instance of ApplicationContext is being created." into Every time `MvcApplication` is instantiated